# IE 7/8 ignores relative positioned DIV outside of an abolsute positioned DIV

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

okay, here we go… this is my HTML-code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="menu-hauptmenu-container">
        <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
.menu-hauptmenu-container {
position:relative;
max-width:960px;
width:90%;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
height:75px;
}
#header {
position:relative;
width:100%;
background:#eb3d3c;
height:75px;
}
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:106px;
    background: url(img/logo.png) no-repeat center;
    top:0;
    left:5px;
    z-index:9999;
}
    #logo a{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

The problem: IE7/8 ignores the relative positioned ".menu-hauptmenu-container" so that the absolute positioned "#logo" gets positioned outside of the parent DIV.

as always it's hard for me to explain technically thinks in english so:

I know, this will not be well-received but here's the live site:
http://www.thorstenbreyer.de/kunden/pommerel/tcn/ieproblem/

thanks!

Comment: absolute positioned elements are just that, the ignore the position of the parent element

Comment: @Edorka except when the parent is also positioned, of course.

Comment: @MrLister indeed but .menu-hauptmenu-container is position:relative

Comment: @Edorka — And the definition of "a positioned element" is "An element where the value of the `position` property is not `static`". `relative` is not `static` so the element is positioned.

Comment: @Edorka: just look it up in some modern browsers: #logo adapts to .menu-hauptmenu-container like it should (top:0; left:0;) but in IE7/8 it ignores the whole parent (.menu-hauptmenu-container) ..see my posted link!

Comment: @JochenSchmidt I dont have all of your HTML of course, but I think the answer is to ensure that IE8 doesn't display the thing in quirks mode. Make sure the DOCTYPE is OK, make sure you haven't chosen compatibility view, etc. Because it works fine in IE8. (I don't have any access to IE7.)

Comment: @MrLister: Here's the whole code: http://www.thorstenbreyer.de/kunden/pommerel/tcn/ieproblem/

Comment: @Pete That's odd, it does demonstrate the problem for me. Haven't found out what causes it though.

Comment: @Pete: it works fine in IE7 or 8??? i'm testing it right now and the whole main-menu doesn't show up and the logo on the top left gets absolute-positioned to the whole page (not to the relative parent container)..?!?!?!

Comment: That's right yes, the menu isn't visible either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.menu-hauptmenu-container` is inside a media query. IE 7 and 8 ignore media queries so it is not positioned correctly.

Comment: Good one. I should have noticed that on other browsers the same happens when you make the window smaller.